# Error en ordenamiento de burbuja

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa donde se registren los nombres de alumnos y tres calificaciones, despues se tienen que ordenar sus promedios de menor a mayor (yo elegi el metodo de ordenamiento bubble/burbuja) sin embargo me sale el siguiente error:

Calificaciones.java:90: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
            for(int i=1; i

```js
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Calificaciones{
   public static void main (String[]args){
      Scanner entrada;
      entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner entrada2;
      entrada2=new Scanner(System.in);
    
   
      String[]nombre= new String[100];
      int opcion_menu=0; int ejecutar=0; 
      int salir=0;       int passed;
      int flunked;
      
      int promedio[]=new int[100];  
      int otro=0;
      int auxpromedio;
      int auxnombre;
      int a=0;
      int x=0;
      int add=1;
      int y=0;
      int calificacion[]= new int[100];
      int segunda[]=new int[100];
      int tercera[]=new int[100];
   
      do{
     
      
         System.out.println("Elija la opcion deseada \n [1].Captura \n [2].Consulta \n [3].Salida ");
         opcion_menu=entrada.nextInt();
         
         if(opcion_menu>3)
         {
         System.out.println("Favor de ingresar otra opcion del 1 al 3");
         }
         }while(opcion_menu>3 || opcion_menu<1);
         
          do{
         if(opcion_menu==1)
         
         {
      
       
       
            System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del alumno:");
        nombre[a]=sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
          add=add+1;
           do{
            System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion del primer parcial:");
            calificacion[a]=entrada.nextInt();
              if(calificacion[a]>=11)
            {
            System.out.println("ERROR \nIngresa un valor no mayor de 10");
           
            }
         }while(calificacion[a]>10 || calificacion[a]<1);
        
            System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion del segundo parcial");
            segunda[a]=entrada.nextInt();
               if(calificacion[a]>=11)
            {
            System.out.println("ERROR \nIngresa un valor no mayor de 10");
           
            }
         }while(calificacion[a]>10 || calificacion[a]<1);
        
            System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion del tercer parcial");
            tercera[a]=entrada.nextInt();
            promedio[x]=(calificacion[x]+segunda[x]+tercera[x])/3;
            do{
            if(calificacion[a]>=11)
            {
            System.out.println("ERROR \nIngresa un valor no mayor de 10");
           
            }
         }while(calificacion[a]>10 || calificacion[a]<1);
        System.out.println("Deseas ingresar otras calificaciones? \n 1.Si \n 2.No");
        otro=entrada.nextInt();
        
           }while(otro==1); 
           
            if(opcion_menu==2){
            System.out.println("Consultas de promedios");
            for(int i=1; i<promedio; i++)
            {
            for(y=1; y<promedio; y++);
            if(promedio[y]>promedio[y+1])
            {
            
            auxpromedio=promedio[y];
            promedio[y]=promedio[y+1];
            promedio[y+1]=auxpromedio;
            auxnombre=nombre[y];
            nombre[y]=nombre[y+1];
            nombre[y+1]=auxnombre;
            }
           
            }
            
            }
            
       if(opcion_menu==3)
         {
            
              System.out.println("¿Desea salir del programa? 1. Si 2. No");
           salir=entrada.nextInt();
                 
             if(salir==1){
          
               System.exit(0);
              System.out.println("Gracias por usar el programa");
              }
              }
   }
}
```

Comment: Veo de nuevo unos cuantos errores en el código, similares a los de tu pregunta anterior, te los detallo en una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empecemos por la línea donde defines `int promedio[] =new int[100];`, deberías cambiarlo por `int[] promedio = new int[100];` para recordarte que es una matriz de enteros nada más ver la definición.

Seguimos con la entrada de datos, donde vas introduciendo todo en el índice `a` (`nombre[a] = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase()`) pero agregas la variable `add` en su lugar (`add=add+1;`), de modo que siempre estarás escribiendo en la misma posición de las matrices. Lo cambio todo por `add` y, además, empiezo por `0` e incremento al final de la introducción de datos.

Ten cuidado con la aritmética de enteros. En el interior de los bucles de comprobación estás usando la comparación `if(calificacion[a]>=11)` y luego en el exterior usas `}while(calificacion[a]>10 || calificacion[a]<1);`. Es equivalente en enteros, pero si algún día aplicas aritmética de coma flotante (para implementar decimales) te encontrarás comportamientos extraños (como poder introducir calificaciones entre el 10 y el 11, como 10.5). Además, te recomiendo poner exactamente la misma comprobación en ambos sitios para que te salga un mensaje en caso de un valor negativo (tal y como lo tienes no lo haría).

El primer bloque  `do {` parece que no está abierto.

La segunda y tercera calificación la almacenas en `segunda[a]=entrada.nextInt();` pero luego compruebas los límites introducidos haciendo referencia a la matriz anterior, `calificacion` ().

Para el bloque de la segunda calificación no abres la llave del `do {`, pero la cierras, por lo que descuadras la estructura del código.

Al introducir la tercera calificación inmediatamente calculas el promedio, en vez de esperar a la comprobación de los límites, además que abres el `do {` posteriormente. Lo he cambiado al lugar adecuado.

En la opción 2 tienes un bucle cerrado inmediatamente `for(y=1; y<promedio; y++);` que impide la ejecución cíclica del siguiente bloque `{}`.

Por otro lado, en ambos bucles estás usando `promedio` como variable a la que debe llegar buscando los elementos a ordenar, cuando el número de elementos en las matrices está almacenado en `add` (antiguamente una mezcolanza entre `a` a `add`). **Como `promedio` es una matriz, te genera ese error que sufres**.

Pones un mensaje de salida posterior a la ejecución de la salida `System.exit(0)`, por lo que nunca se mostrará.

El bucle exterior `do {` que comprueba el menú y lo repite en caso de no salir, ya que no usas el valor de `menu_salida` deberías poner un `while (true);` (de hecho da error por no tener nada).

La línea `nombre[y+1] = auxnombre;` está mal si defines `auxnombre` como entero. Debes cambiarlo por `String auxnombre;`.

Tu código arreglado sería (ojo, no has hecho nada para mostrar el resultado de la ordenación):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Calificaciones {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner entrada2 = new Scanner(System.in);

      String[] nombre = new String[100];
      String auxnombre;
      int opcion_menu=0, ejecutar=0, salir=0;
      int passed = 0, flunked = 0;

      int promedio[] =new int[100];
      int otro = 0, auxpromedio;
      int a = 0, x = 0, add = 1, y = 0;
      int calificacion[] = new int[100];
      int segunda[] = new int[100];
      int tercera[] = new int[100];

      do {
        System.out.println("Elija la opcion deseada");
        System.out.println("[1]. Captura");
        System.out.println("[2]. Consulta");
        System.out.println("[3]. Salida ");
        opcion_menu = entrada.nextInt();
        switch (opcion_menu) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del alumno:");
          nombre[add] = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
          do {
            do {
              System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion del primer parcial:");
              calificacion[add] = entrada.nextInt();
              if(calificacion[add] < 1 || calificacion[add] > 10) {
                System.out.println("ERROR \nIngresa un valor no mayor de 10");
              }
            } while (calificacion[add] > 10 || calificacion[add] < 1);
            do {
              System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion del segundo parcial");
              segunda[add] = entrada.nextInt();
              if (segunda[add] < 1 || segunda[add] > 10) {
                System.out.println("ERROR \nIngresa un valor no mayor de 10");
              }
            } while (segunda[add] > 10 || segunda[add] < 1);
            do {
              System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion del tercer parcial");
              tercera[add]=entrada.nextInt();
              if (tercera[add] < 1 || tercera[add] > 10) {
                System.out.println("ERROR \nIngresa un valor no mayor de 10");
              }
            } while (tercera[add] < 1 || tercera[add] > 10);
            promedio[x]=(calificacion[x]+segunda[x]+tercera[x])/3;
            add++;
            System.out.println("Deseas ingresar otras calificaciones? \n 1.Si \n 2.No");
            otro=entrada.nextInt();
          } while (otro == 1);
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("Consultas de promedios");
          for (int i = 0; i < add; i++) {
            for (y = 1; y < add; y++) {
              if (promedio[y] > promedio[y+1]) {
                auxpromedio = promedio[y];
                promedio[y] = promedio[y+1];
                promedio[y+1] = auxpromedio;
                auxnombre = nombre[y];
                nombre[y] = nombre[y+1];
                nombre[y+1] = auxnombre;
              }
            }
          }
          break;
        case 3:
          System.out.println("¿Desea salir del programa? 1. Si 2. No");
          salir = entrada.nextInt();
          if (salir == 1) {
            System.out.println("Gracias por usar el programa");
            System.exit(0);
          }
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Favor de ingresar otra opcion del 1 al 3");
        }
      } while (true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisé tu código y tiene problemas de sintaxis ya que declaras lo siguiente:

```
    for(int i=1; i<promedio; i++)
```

Debiese ser así:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < promedio.length; i++)
```

Tu código resultante debe verse así:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Calificaciones {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada;
        entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner entrada2;
        entrada2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] nombre = new String[100];
        int opcion_menu = 0;
        int ejecutar = 0;
        int salir = 0;
        int passed;
        int flunked;

        int promedio[] = new int[100];
        int otro = 0;
        int auxpromedio;
        String auxnombre;
        int a = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int add = 1;
        int y = 0;
        int calificacion[] = new int[100];
        int segunda[] = new int[100];
        int tercera[] = new int[100];

        do {

            System.out.println("Elija la opcion deseada \n [1].Captura \n [2].Consulta \n [3].Salida ");
            opcion_menu = entrada.nextInt();

            if (opcion_menu > 3) {
                System.out.println("Favor de ingresar otra opcion del 1 al 3");
            }
        } while (opcion_menu > 3 || opcion_menu < 1);

        do {
            if (opcion_menu == 1)

            {

                System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del alumno:");
                nombre[a] = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                add = add + 1;
                do {
                    System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion del primer parcial:");
                    calificacion[a] = entrada.nextInt();
                    if (calificacion[a] >= 11) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR \nIngresa un valor no mayor de 10");

                    }
                } while (calificacion[a] > 10 || calificacion[a] < 1);

                System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion del segundo parcial");
                segunda[a] = entrada.nextInt();
                if (calificacion[a] >= 11) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR \nIngresa un valor no mayor de 10");

                }
            }
            while (calificacion[a] > 10 || calificacion[a] < 1)
                ;

            System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion del tercer parcial");
            tercera[a] = entrada.nextInt();
            promedio[x] = (calificacion[x] + segunda[x] + tercera[x]) / 3;
            do {
                if (calificacion[a] >= 11) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR \nIngresa un valor no mayor de 10");

                }
            } while (calificacion[a] > 10 || calificacion[a] < 1);
            System.out.println("Deseas ingresar otras calificaciones? \n 1.Si \n 2.No");
            otro = entrada.nextInt();

        } while (otro == 1);

        if (opcion_menu == 2) {
            System.out.println("Consultas de promedios");
            for (int i = 1; i < promedio.length; i++) {
                for (y = 1; y < promedio.length; y++)
                    ;
                if (promedio[y] > promedio[y + 1]) {

                    auxpromedio = promedio[y];
                    promedio[y] = promedio[y + 1];
                    promedio[y + 1] = auxpromedio;
                    auxnombre = nombre[y];
                    nombre[y] = nombre[y + 1];
                    nombre[y + 1] = auxnombre;
                }

            }

        }

        if (opcion_menu == 3) {

            System.out.println("¿Desea salir del programa? 1. Si 2. No");
            salir = entrada.nextInt();

            if (salir == 1) {

                System.exit(0);
                System.out.println("Gracias por usar el programa");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `promedio.length` va a valer siempre 100, por lo que la causa raíz del problema no es ese. Simplemente se ha equivocado de variable, debió usar `add` (variable que almacena los registros introducidos) en su lugar.

Answer (score 0):

En Java yo usaria la interface `Comparator` donde delegas la tarea de comparar a un objeto distinto, esto hara que la logica de ordenamiento se desacople de la logica original, ambas sean mantenibles y tu codigo queda mas claro para ti y para otro que lo vea. Suerte!!!

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // se construye la lista en el mismo orden que se agregan los estudiantes: Harold, Daniel y Victor
        List<Student> students = buildStudents();
        System.out.println(students);
        // se ordena la lista por promedio de menor a mayor: Victor, Harold y Daniel
        Collections.sort(students, new QualificationComparator());
        System.out.println(students);
    }

    private static List<Student> buildStudents() {

        List<Student> studens = new ArrayList<Student>();

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("Harold");
        student.setQualifications(Arrays.asList(98.2d, 75.34d, 64.0d));
        studens.add(student);

        student = new Student();
        student.setName("Daniel");
        student.setQualifications(Arrays.asList(100.0d, 87.5d, 92.1d));
        studens.add(student);

        student = new Student();
        student.setName("Victor");
        student.setQualifications(Arrays.asList(81.3d, 62.9d, 43.54d));
        studens.add(student);

        return studens;
    }

    static class Student {

        private String name;

        private List<Double> qualifications;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Double> getQualifications() {
            return qualifications;
        }

        public void setQualifications(List<Double> qualifications) {
            this.qualifications = qualifications;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

    }

    static class QualificationComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Student student, Student studentToCompare) {

            Double average = calculateAverage(student.getQualifications());
            Double averageToCompare = calculateAverage(studentToCompare.getQualifications());

            return average.compareTo(averageToCompare);
        }

        private Double calculateAverage(List<Double> qualifications) {

            // usamos BigDecimal para no perder precision
            BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0d);

            for (Double qualification : qualifications) {
                result = result.add(new BigDecimal(qualification));
            }

            BigDecimal length = new BigDecimal(qualifications.size());
            // dividimos y redondeamos hacia arriba
            BigDecimal average = result.divide(length, RoundingMode.CEILING);

            return average.doubleValue();
        }

    }

}
```